# how do i arrange contents in a file in alphabetical order

Tags: python, pygame

And I have this ERROR.

[image]

**I TRIED THIS BUT IT IS GIVING ME AN ERROR**

```
import time
import pygame


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
red= (255,0,0)
black =(0,0,0)
white =(255,255,255)

EXIT= False
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)

def alert(msg,color):
    text = font.render(msg,True,color)
    screen.blit(text,[250,300])

while not EXIT:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.QUIT:
                EXIT =True

    screen.fill(White)
    pygame.display.update()
alert("TESTING ALERT 1,2,3",red)

pygame.display.update()
time.sleep(3)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: I could not get the code to show perfectly please bear with me

Comment: Please give a meaningful subject, format code properly and trim down to relevant parts (if needed at all), provide the error message as text, not as an image where relevant parts are cropped.

Comment: I suspect that `None` is not a valid font name. Use the name of the font you want to use.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner That's not the problem. Using `None` will result in pygame using a default font, so it's fine to use.

Comment: @CurtisCrentsil did the answer posted below helped?

Comment: @CurtisCrentsil you may consider accepting the answer if it helped: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Comment: @DirtyBit so for the late reply i was so happy the code worked, that i didn't remember to comment or even up vote the answer, it did thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Error**:

> pygame.error: font not initialized

I could hardly read the error from your attached image.

**A couple of fixes**:

1. Initialize `pygame.init()`
2. You are using `White` in the `screen.fill()` function, should be `white` instead.

**Hence**:

```
import time
import pygame

pygame.init()   #  initialize the pygame modules
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
red = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

EXIT= False
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)  

def alert(msg,color):
    text = font.render(msg,True,color)
    screen.blit(text,[250,300])

while not EXIT:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.QUIT:
                EXIT =True

    screen.fill(white)     # Notice the case sensitivity
    pygame.display.update()
alert("TESTING ALERT 1,2,3",red)

pygame.display.update()
time.sleep(3)
pygame.quit()
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

[image: out]

Comment: @sloth I was in doubt about it, fixed. Thank you! :)